# SSRS - T-SQL - Concatenate multiple rows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have T-SQL query that joins multiple tables. I am using that in SSRS as Dataset query. I am only selecting two columns, ID and Names. I have three records with same "ID" values but three different "Names" values. In SSRS, I am getting the first "Names" value and I need to concatonate all three values with same ID and have it in one cell on a table.

How would I go about doing that?

I am using lookup to combine cube + sql
Pulling ID straight from a table but using Case statement for Names to define alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in TSQL either using [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get them as separate columns which you can then combine in the report cell, or you can use one of [these](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) concatenation methods to get all the names in one column.

For example, you can do this:

```
SELECT  SomeTableA.Id,
        STUFF(
          (SELECT ',' + SomeTableB.Names AS [text()]
           FROM SomeTable SomeTableB
           WHERE SomeTableB.Id = SomeTableA.Id
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )
        AS ConcatenatedNames
FROM  SomeTable SomeTableA
INNER JOIN AnotherTable
  ON SomeTableA.Id = AnotherTable.SomeId
...
```

Comment: I have more than one columns (I just mentioned ID and Names for this example; I do NOT want to  PIVOT every single rows into columns. I just want to combine 1 columns records into a string in a cell. For one ID, I have three rows (SAME ID VALUES) and then 1 more column for Names (3 different names). This T-SQL code will be used in SSRS so it won't work. I am also getting data from MULTIPLE tables by doing INNER JOIN. I am stuck

Comment: Concatenating in TSQL using FOR XML PATH would certainly work for you.  SSRS just passes the query along to the database, so any valid SQL will work.  You can also move this logic into a stored procedure, and call that from the report (recommended). [Here](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/) is another link that demonstrates the concatenation a bit more clearly.  See updated answer for how you might do this including a join to another table.